# Create a variable of an array by fetchRow of a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a variable named $period1 by using the value of $info[per1] to fetchRow from the classes table in a MySQL database. I'm using the following code to make the MySQL call. I am connected properly, I'm able to

**My code...**

```
$info = $db->fetchRow("select * from `profiles` where `username` =?", array($logged_in));
$period1 = $db->fetchRow("select * from `classes` where `name` =?", array($info[per1]));
```

The following prints **Web Design** and is what I use to search the classes table.

```
<?php echo $info[per1]?>
```

**classes table**

```
id  name           teacher   cost   
1   Web Design     Benrud    999
```

**The results of the echos**

```
<?php echo $period1?>
```

returns: Array

```
<?php echo $period1[1]?>
```

returns: a blank

Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: "You're not having any luck-" how do you know? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @esqewm, Blank print. I'm still VERY new to php/mysql.

Comment: have you looked at fetch_array?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Share any and all code relevant to the problem to help us more accurately identify your particular issue (with sensitive information redacted, i.e. passwords). There may be issues with the way you're connecting to the database or creating the database instance in the first place.

Comment: Just a housekeeping note: You can post your biography on your profile. There is no reason to add "Thanks for your help! -Todd, High School Teacher" to every single question you post.

Comment: @George, thanks for letting me know this is a problem. I was unaware that a valediction is improper etiquette here. I will not do so going forward.

Comment: @esqeq, I'm running to a meeting right not. I will post the info you requested in about an hour. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Switch to MySQLi, MySQL has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.x

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [0] or [2] or [3] I tried using the table column name. The following worked

```
<?php echo $period1[teacher]?>
```

Comment: When using that method, it's better to type `$period1['teacher']` or you'll get "Notice:" errors in your logs. because `teacher` is first seen as a constant and then guessed to be a string.

Comment: @scrowler, thank! Hopefully I'll be able to do it more frequently.

Comment: @TecBrat, thank you for the suggestion. I will make the change.